# how to customize an table in oracle sql

Tags: oracle11g

I need to know how to customize the table in oracle sql
by not repeating the same records or names using the month validations

My query goes like this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.CUST_CODE,
       CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME,
       TRANS_MASTER.JOB_DATE,
       TRANS_DETAIL.QUANTITY

  FROM TRANS_MASTER,
       TRANS_DETAIL,
       CUSTOMERS

 WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUST_CODE = TRANS_MASTER.CUST_CODE

 GROUP BY 
       CUSTOMERS.CUST_CODE, 
       TRANS_MASTER.JOB_DATE, 
       CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME, 
       TRANS_DETAIL.QUANTITY

 ORDER BY 
       CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME,
       TRANS_MASTER.JOB_DATE ASC
```

here i'm using 3 tables

1. Customer
2. Master
3. Detail (child)

**i need query help!**

and also how to display the date as month name in oracle sql.

thanks